# ¿Como coloco barra sobre un carácter en LaTeX?

Tags: latex

Encontré en la página de ShareLaTeX/Overleaf que para colocar una barra sobre un carácter se utilizaba:

```
\bar{a}
```

Así lo intenté pero no sale nada, en otras páginas encuentro lo mismo. ¿Cual es el comando correcto, fue actualizado o algo así?

Answer (score 3):

Ese comando sólo puede usarse dentro del modo matemático. Fuera de él, obtendrás un error. Úsalo así:

```
$\bar{a}$
```

y obtendrás

[image: a-cursiva con barra]

Al estar en modo matemático, la letra sale cursiva (pues representa una variable). Si necesitaras que saliera "normal", puedes usar este truco (requiere el paquete `amstext`, que ya tendrás cargado si estabas usando `amsmath`):

```
$\bar{\text{a}}$
```

[image: a-roman con barra]

Por otro lado, tienes también el comando `\overline` (de nuevo sólo funciona en modo matemático) que admite como parámetro no ya una sola letra, sino una palabra completa, poniendo la barra sobre toda ella. Puedes ponerlo también sobre una sola letra. La línea que usa es un poco más gruesa que la de `\bar`.

Finalmente, en modo texto existe un tipo especial de acento `\=` que se ve como una barra sobre la letra en cuestión.

Así que tienes todas estas opciones:

```
$\overline{\text{a}}$
\={a}
$\bar{\text{a}}$
```

Que se ven así:

[image: Varias a con barra]

Comment: Tienes razón, y de hecho siempre me sirvió. Es que si no hago un zoom en especifico en Overleaf no sale la barra, pero siempre estuvo ahí (donde se cumplía el detalle que me compartes ahora). Gracias por la información extra, cuando pueda te marco la respuesta.